# Глобальная переменная для dll

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Как объявить глобальную переменную в основной программе чтобы затем,в dll получить к ней доступ?

Comment: Ставьте пометку `_export` (а в библиотеках `extern`), и сможете её прилинковать (как автоматом, что сложнее, так и вручную).

Comment: Но лучше бы этого не делать, поскольку после изменения основной программы надо перелинковать библиотеку, иначе будут падения, а это в свою очерь потребует перелинковки основной программы. Глобальные переменные и без таких извращений довольно неудобны и опасны. Лучше передать переменную или ссылку на нее в функцию, которая должна этой переменной пользоваться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оптимальный способ доступа к переменной, находящейся в основной программе, из DLL это сделать в библиотеке функцию, которая будет принимать адрес и дальше работать с переменной через этот адрес. Пример:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void useData(T* data) {
   // используем data-> ...
}
```

В программе же вызывать эту функцию, передавая адрес глобальной переменной:

```
T gData;
useData(&gData);
```

Answer (score 0):

В итоге, как сделал:
в главной функции exe объявил функцию из dll следующим образом:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void _stdcall setHwnd(HWND*, HHOOK*);
```

Затем, в dll завёл две static - переменные, которые буду хранить нужные мне значения. И далее, вызвал эту функцию в главной программе:

```
setHwnd(&hwnd_main, &hCBTHook);
```

В dll функция выглядит так:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void _stdcall setHwnd(HWND* hwnd, HHOOK* hhook)
{
    hwnd_main = *hwnd;
    hCBTHook = *hhook;
}
```

И всё работает. Спасибо.

Comment: Что-то у Вас не хватает названий параметров. И судя по всему происходит самоприсваивание, т.е. бесполезная операция.

Comment: @alexolut просто когда писал сообщение, не стал копировать реализацию функции из студии, а дописал руками, забыв про параметры)